# Average values of one column based on the values of another

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe with a column that has many repeated values in one column. I want to create another dataframe that has only one instance of that value paired with the average of it's matching values from another column of the original dataframe.
Example:

```
data = [[1,1],[1,2],[2,2],[3,3],[3,1],[2,3],[1,5],[2,7],[3,9]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['A', 'B'])
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  2  2
3  3  3
4  3  1
5  2  3
6  1  5
7  2  7
8  3  9
```

I want to average column B values that match the same column A values. then have a new dataframe that look like this:

```
  A  B
0  1  2.7
1  2  4
2  3  4.3
```

I did this by looping:

```
df2 = pdDataFrame(columns = ['A','B'])
uni = df.A.unique()
for x in uni:
    av = df.loc[(df['A'] == x, 'B')].mean()
    df2 = df2.append(pd.DataFrame([[x, av]], columns = ['A', 'B']))
```

I know it is not good form to loop through an DataFrame and this process took forever. It also resulted in a DataFrame without an index (they were all 0). What is a more appropriate and efficient method to do this. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply:

```
df.groupby('A')[['B']].mean().reset_index()
    A      B
0   1   2.666667
1   2   4.000000
2   3   4.333333
```

If you want `B` rounded:

```
df.groupby('A')[['B']].mean().round(1).reset_index()
    A    B
0   1   2.7
1   2   4.0
2   3   4.3
```

Or even this way, not using `A` as index, with argument `as_index=False`:

```
df.groupby('A', as_index=False)[['B']].mean().round(1)
    A    B
0   1   2.7
1   2   4.0
2   3   4.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may group your table by the column `"A"` and compute the mean for every such a group:

```
df.groupby("A").mean()
```

---

The result:

> ```
>       B
> A     
> 1     2.666667
> 2     4.000000
> 3     4.333333
> ```